# python split, why am I not seeing all the hyphens in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
test_string = '----a---b--c-d'
a = test_string.split('-')
print(a)
```

### OUTPUT

```
['', '', '', '', 'a', '', '', 'b', '', 'c', 'd']
```

I'm assuming the empty list items ('') are the hyphens. My question is, why between a and b are there only two '' and not three like in the input?

Answer (score 3):

let's replace the empty fields by some string:

```
test_string = '<field>-<field>-<field>-<field>-a-<field>-<field>-b-<field>-c-d'
```

now you see clearly where the fields are located.

You can see that there are only 2 fields between `a` and `b`. Special case is at the start of the string, where the empty string at the start is also seen as a field.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` uses its argument as a delimiter, and so won't include it in the list it returns.

The same goes when using `re.split(r'-', test_string)`, unless you put the *pattern* in parentheses.  So if you really want to keep the `-` when splitting a string, I suggest you do something like this:

```
test_string = '----a---b--c-d'

import re
a = re.split(r'(-)', test_string)
print(a)
```

This will print out:

```
['', '-', '', '-', '', '-', '', '-', 'a', '-', '', '-', '', '-', 'b', '-', '', '-', 'c', '-', 'd']
```

If you're wondering why there are a lot of empty strings in this output, it's because `re.split` will keep whatever is between the `-` characters, *even if they are strings of zero length*.

A shorter example might help to understand what's going on:

```
test_string = 'cat-dog-bird'

import re
a = re.split(r'(-)', test_string)
print(a)
```

This will print out:

```
['cat', '-', 'dog', '-', 'bird']
```

If you don't want the `-` characters, then remove the parentheses from `r'(-)'`.  That is, change `r'(-)'` to `r'-'`, or just use:

```
a = test_string.split('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is default split() function operation.

So basically if you separate between to other characters, you always get x-

> Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns [''].

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: fullblown copy&paste of python 2 documentation that could have been linked in comment - beside that it is a python 3 questions. why copy the docu?

Comment: You have a point about python2, on top of the answer there is some explanation too.